Confusion on Bayesian Cramer-Rao Lower Bound Calculation
I am studying the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound (CRLB) with a prior knowledge for extra length due to none-line-of-sight (NLOS). The articles I am reading are On geolocation accuracy with prior information in non-line-of-sight environment and Analysis of wireless geolocation in a non-line-of-sight environment. Both are from the same authors and discussed similar things. The equation of extended CRB algorithm is
$$J = \frac{1}{c^2}\left( \begin{bmatrix} H_{NL}\Lambda_{NL}H_{NL}^T+H_{L}\Lambda_{L}H_{L}^T & H_{NL}\Lambda_{NL} \\ \Lambda_{NL}H_{NL} & \Lambda_{NL}+c^2\Omega \end{bmatrix} \right),$$
where $H_{NL}$ and $H_L$ are the matrix of angle for NLOS and LOS base stations, respectively. $\Lambda$ stands for the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}8\pi^2\beta^2\cdot R_b$ which computed from the received signal. $\Omega = \operatorname{diag}(\sigma^2_l)$ is the prior known covariance matrix for the NLOS delays. And the equation is shown in eq.(20)(21) for the first article and eq.(50) in the second.
Since the localization only cares the $(x,y)$ position, only the upper sub-matrix is considered, which means that the prior knowledge of the NLOS delays $\sigma^2_l$ are not really influence the calculation. The papers also mentioned that when the prior NLOS delay's variance is really large, which $\sigma^2_l \rightarrow +\infty$, the $H_{NL}\Lambda_{NL}H_{NL}^T$ will be reduced; and if $\sigma^2_l \rightarrow 0$, the NLOS part can be treated as a LOS estimates.
What makes me confused is, those papers still gives me no idea on how to calculate the CRB within prior knownledge of the NLOS delays. For example, with totally 10 rx radar, I know 2 of them is LOS and the rest 8 is NLOS. And with prior knowledge I know the NLOS delays are in distribution that $\sigma^2 = 0.5$. So the calcualtion of the localization CRB should be $H_{NL}\Lambda_{NL}H_{NL}^T+H_L \Lambda_L H_L^T$ (consider $8+2$ receivers) or $H_L\Lambda_{L}H_L^T$ (consider 2 LOS only)? What about if the variance is 1 or 2 or even 10?
For me, the "prior knowledge" seems not be used to calculate the CRB, but also gives a judgement that if some of the radar information should not be considered in the calculation.
